# accepts_nested_attributes_for building form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am getting an error: Undefined method build for nil:NilClass when trying to build an empty child object for my form.

```
class PatientsController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def new
    @patient = Patient.new

    # THIS CAUSES AN ERROR (undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass)
    @patient.user.build 
  end
end    

class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
  attr_accessible :user_id, :user_attributes
end

# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: patients
#
#  id         :integer         not null, primary key
#  user_id    :integer
#  created_at :datetime
#  updated_at :datetime
#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since the Patient belongs to the user you need to build the Patient from the user.

```
@user.patients.build(params[:patient])
```

Patient.new is basically used to create a blank instance of a Patient that you can render on say a new form, but when posting to a create you need to build it from a user.

Comment: I am trying to create a new form and have a patient object that is empty. Many sources said to use build. The User has_one patient and the patient belongs_to a user. The form will have some patient information and user information that needs to be saved across 2 tables.

Comment: build is used when you are actually creating the object to have it saved in the database.  to just have a form which allows you to post a new instance you would just need to do a @patient = Patient.new.  I guess the big thing is do not mix and match the two here

Comment: its tough to tell you specifically how to implement that but generally you would want to create a form for the new patient, create an instance variable in your controller via Patient.new which you pass to the form, and then when you submit the form you need to be able to create the user object (be it via session or by passing in a :user_id with your form) from which you can build the patient as shown above.

Comment: also i failed to mention this before but the User model should accept_nested_attributes for the Patient model.  The Patient belongs to the User model, meaning that it is a nested attribute of a User.  You have that backwards

Comment: I switched it around and tried to do:

    @patient = User.new
    @patient.patient.build

but I still get the nil errror

Comment: because the patient belongs to a user, the user has to be there to build off of.  User.new is no real instance of a user so you are building on nil.  i think before anything you should rethink your relationships and also brush up on them a bit, but anyway you would need to first find a created user like so @user = User.find(params[:user_id]) and then build off that user: @user.patients.build().  hope this helps

Comment: Ok, the way my relationships work are as follows: There are 4 types of users (Patient, Client, ClientAdmin, and SuperAdmin) which all have the same type of basic information in the users table (name, address.etc).

I got it working from the model where I could do Patient.new(insurance: => "blue cross", user_attributes:{...}). But as you said, I am not really allowed to do that. (They are reversed)

It doesn't seem odd to me that a patient can accept attributes for it parent. The model code worked fine. The form builder just doesn't like it.

Do you have any suggestions on my modeling of data?

Comment: modeling is a pretty important issue and its really tough to tell someone exactly which path to go down with only a little knowledge of their application as the implications are pretty large.  in any case i suggest you check out the following link and see what associations you want to establish before doing anything else [link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Comment: So you are saying it is 100% wrong to have a Patient object (which belongs_to a User) accepts_nested_attributes_for :user? I think I have a valid use case for it. Does the database structure at least make sense? USERS: id, user_id, first_name...etc PATIENTS: id, user_id, insurance...I am just trying to following the resources convention by creating a patient from the controller. Should I have just a users controller methods for each type of user?

Comment: right it is wrong :-).  The User is the parent which means that any Patient you create belongs to (note: belongs_to) a user.  Since it is a parent it can have child (nested) elements which would be your patients, and therefore IT can accept nested attributes.  But patients is a child which means that it has no nested elements and therefore should not be accepting nested attributes.  Your structure if I understand right should be USERS: id, first_name...has_many :PATIENTS...etc PATIENTS: id, user_id, insurance...belongs_to :USERS...etc

Comment: Ok I think I am starting to get it: I think the only part I need to clear up is the relationship between USERS and PATIENTS. A user has_one (and only one) PATIENT and a PATIENT belongs_to a USER. Basically Users are abstract and are used for common information between different user types. Is this a bad approach?

Comment: the approach is fine and certainly works.  you can read up on the belongs_to and has_one relation in section 2.7 of the first link i shared with you.  just be aware that if you are getting duplicate records in your Users table then it would be better to go with a belongs_to has_many, but otherwise like i said what you have is certainly valid

Comment: Ok I think I got the model right, but for the controller will it be possible to have a PatientsController actually do the creating of a Patient with user information or should the User create the patient (which wouldn't follow the resources model)?

Comment: you will want to pass the id of the user (:user_id) in and do a @user = User.find(params[:user_id]) and then from there @user.patients.build...etc

Comment: But if I don't know the user_id (IE: New Patient) how do I make a form?

Comment: might want to make a new question for that, but in any case make a instance variable in your controller @patient = Patient.new along with a @user instance variable and then do a <%= form_for [@user, @patient] do |f| %> this will allow you to pass all the necessary variables to a controller action via post